# Joining Angular model data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using ui-router states and resolve to seperate resources - a list "submissions" and a list of "topics". In my controller, I have the two sets of data:

```
...
app.controller('SubmitController', function ($scope, submissions, topics{
  $scope.submissions = submissions;
  $scope.topics = topics;
...
```

Then in the html, something like **(the last few lines of comment code explain what I need**):

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="sub in submissions">
  <td ng-bind="sub.id"></td>
  <td ng-bind="sub.title"></td>
  <td ng-bind="sub.topic_id"></td>
  <td ng-bind="sub.status"></td>
  <!-- 
    here I need a <td> with the "name" from the topic collection
    where the current submission id = the matching topic id from 
    the topic collection
   -->
...
```

I've tried filters and not been able to get it to work. What's the best way to approach something like this?

TIA

Comment: Can you show the properties of each submission and topic object?

Comment: The applicable fields are: submission.topic_id, topic.id, and topic.name. I need to get the topic.name from the topic object where the current ng-repeat submission.topic_id is equal to that names topic.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the topic name based on the topic id, you have to find the topic in the topics array, then assign the name into each submission object.

```
angular.forEach($scope.submissions, function(submission) {
  var topic = $scope.topics.filter(function(tp) {
    return tp.id = submission.topic_id;
  })[0]; //Find the topic base on topic_id
  submission.topicName = topic.name;
});
```

Working snippet below, click "Run code snippet" to see it:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.submissions = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'title 1',
    topic_id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'title 2',
    topic_id: 2
  }, {
    id: 3,
    title: 'title 3',
    topic_id: 2
  }];

  $scope.topics = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'topic 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'topic 2'
  }];

  angular.forEach($scope.submissions, function(submission) {
    var topic = $scope.topics.filter(function(tp) {
      return tp.id == submission.topic_id;
    })[0];
    submission.topicName = topic.name;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Topic Id</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Topic name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="sub in submissions">
        <td ng-bind="sub.id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="sub.title"></td>
        <td ng-bind="sub.topic_id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="sub.status"></td>
        <td ng-bind="sub.topicName"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't upvote due to lack of rep, but that works well and thanks!

Comment: actually in further testing, this is always returning the first topic name... any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. The return should be "==" instead of "=". You can check my edited answer and accept it if it worked.

Comment: Oops... I should have noticed that too... anyway it works now and answer accepted and upvoted - many thanks for the quick replies!